# Best variant (common, more common, the most common)

Tags: word-choice

Can you please help me to choose the most appropriate variant for the following sentence:

In the USA (common, more common, the most common) college degree among the others is a bachelor of arts.

I suppose "more common" as well as "the most common" make sence.
But my teacher insist on just "common".

Native speakers, what variant sounds better in English? Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, *among the others* is not good grammar here, so that needs fixing. *Common* on its own only works with *a*.

So either:

> In the USA, a common college degree is the bachelor of arts.

Or:

> In the USA, the most common college degree is the bachelor of arts.

If you need to keep some form of *among others*, perhaps try something like this:

> In the USA, a common degree, among others, is the bachelor of arts.

(I must say, though, it's hard to fit among others in here in any kind of useful way.)

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. May I ask one more question? What is wrong with the article in "among the others"? Is it because we didn't spesify the exact degrees? But I assume there exist not so many of them,

Comment: @Natalie The problem isn’t with using “the” with “others” - that part is fine. It’s with using “common” with “among the others”. That would be ok as well if “others” meant “other people”. But “common” *among* “other degrees” doesn’t really make sense. It restricts the universe of discussion to “other degrees”, making the one you’re highlighting *out of scope*, let alone *common*.

Comment: *Among others* is a common phrase that means the thing you are talking about is one of many—but those others are undefined. You can't say "the others" in this context unless you've already identified/named those others.